# get .outerHeight of element if visible

Tags: jquery, visible, outerheight

Im woundering if its possible to get `.outerHeight()` of element only if its is visible

I currently have

```
var $viewItem = $('.test').find('.item');

var viewItemHeight = $viewItem.outerHeight(true);
```

The problem is `$viewItem`

Will return two elements at a time, one will be hidden. If is possible to test and only get the height of the visible one ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about the visible selector?

```
var $viewItem = $('.test').find('.item:visible');
var viewItemHeight = $viewItem.outerHeight(true);
```